# Test WinXP look on other platforms?

Tags: qt

Is there a way to test the look of my UI on Windows or other platforms from my Linux machine?  I'd like to have some idea of how it will look without having to rebuilding the project on a windows machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the command line for your program you can specify the style:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qapplication.html#QApplication

> -style= style, sets the application GUI style. Possible values depend on your system configuration. If you compiled Qt with additional styles or have additional styles as plugins these will be available to the -style command line option. You can also set the style for all Qt applications by setting the QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE environment variable.

In some [older documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qapplication.html#QApplication) it mentions:

> Possible values are motif, windows, and platinum.

I just tried this on Windows 8 with Qt 4.8.4, and I got no change adding in "style=platinum" or any of the others, and apparently the build of Qt that I got did not come with the additional style plugins.  So, build Qt with the additional styles, and then you can preview the look for other OS's.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Seems to the thing I'm looking for.  I can change the style to motif but not others.  I'm guessing the problem is I didn't install them.